# Decorated python function with parameters only used by the decorator are seen as unused

Tags: python, parameters, decorator

I have a number of functions that are RPC calls and all have to prepare several things before the main task and to do some cleanup afterwards. Especially their first two parameters are `logname` and `password` which are needed to setup user data (properties, rights etc.).

So I decided to build a decorator called `@rpc_wrapper` which performs these tasks. This wrapper is now working fine for more than a year. The only drawback is that the `inspect code` function of *PyCharm* – I think other linters will behave similar – complains about the parameters `logname` and `password` which are never used inside of the function but only by the decorator.

How can I get rid of these complaints?

One way might be to insert a line

```py
    assert (logname, password)
```

at the start of each function. But I think that's not the real deal because decorators are made to avoid replications.

Is there a cleaner solution?

#### Edited

Here is the (simplified) decorator:

```py
def rpc_wrapper(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(login=None, pwd=None, *args, **kwargs):
        doCleanup = True
        try:
            doCleanup = setupUser(login, pwd)
            return func(login, pwd, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            logging.exception('**<#>')
            raise Exception('999: internal error')
        finally:
            if doCleanup:
                cleanup()
    return wrapper
```

And a decorated function:

```py
@rpc_wrapper
def ping(login: str = None, pwd: str = None):
    return 'pong'
```

or another simple one:

```py
@rpc_wrapper
def echo(login: str = None, pwd: str = None, msg: Any = 'message'):
    return msg
```

Comment: What does your code look like? We can't fix what we can't see.

Comment: If the decorated functions *never* need the `login` and `pwd` parameters, the wrapper shouldn't pass them on.

Comment: @jasonharper I think if I would leave out the two parameters in the function signature the linter would complain at every call of the function about the the two extra parameters :-(